# Query optimization

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with this slow query:

```
SELECT c.*, csc1.changed_status
  FROM contract c
  LEFT
  JOIN contract_status_change csc1
    ON csc1.contract_status_change_id =
        ( SELECT csc2.contract_status_change_id
            FROM contract_status_change csc2
           WHERE csc2.contract_id = c.contract_id
           ORDER
              BY csc2.date_changed DESC
           LIMIT 1
        )
 ;
```

I have a contract table and a contract_status_change table, which records statuses against the contract. This query is joining on the latest status with the contract so you can get its current status..

Please can you help me tidy it up?

-edit-

my apologies. I have updated the query to include selecting the actual latest status out. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: [This](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz) perhaps?

Comment: select
   `c`.*
from 
`contract` `c` left join `contract_status_change` `ls`
 on `ls`.`contract_status_change_id` = `ls`.`contract_status_change_id`
 inner join `contract_status_change` `sc`
 on `c`.`contract_id` = `sc`.`contract_id`
 order by `sc`.`date_changed` desc limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After formatting your query for readability (consistent whitespace and capitalization, removing unnecessary backticks and parentheses, more sensible aliases):

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM contract c
  LEFT
  JOIN contract_status_change csc1
    ON csc1.contract_status_change_id =
        ( SELECT csc2.contract_status_change_id
            FROM contract_status_change csc2
           WHERE csc2.contract_id = c.contract_id
           ORDER
              BY csc2.date_changed DESC
           LIMIT 1
        )
 ;
```

and assuming that `contract_status_change.contract_status_change_id` is a unique identifier, I'm forced to conclude that your query is equivalent to this, much more efficient one:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM contract c
 ;
```

You say that it "is joining on the latest status with the contract so you can get its current status", but it doesn't *do* anything with the current status — doesn't order by it, doesn't filter by it, doesn't include it in the query results — so there's no need for that.

Comment: From his description I think you're right, but maybe he wants to include the csc.date_changed field in his select, but omitted it in his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
This should help a bit.

SELECT c.*, csc1.changed_status
FROM contract c LEFT JOIN contract_changed_status csc1 ON c.contract_id = csc1.contract_id
INNER JOIN 
   (
    SELECT contract_id, changed_status, MAX(date_changed) AS 'max_date' 
    FROM contract_status_changed GROUP_BY contract_id
    GROUP BY contract_id
   ) csc2 ON csc1.contract_id = csc2.contract_id AND csc1.date_changed = csc2.max_date
```